# Animating a 360 degree rotation around another view's center point

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

I'm making a loading spinner animation that pushes a view out from the middle, and then rotates all the way around the center view back to it's original location. This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The inner arrow moves the view away from the center. I've already achieved this, the part I am stuck on is then rotating the view around the center view. I've read various other StackOverflow posts but have not been close to achieving this.

Code so far:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {

            self.topView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 20, y: -20)

        } completion: { _ in
            
            self.topView.setAnchorPoint(self.centerView.center)
                
            // Rotate
            
        }
}
```

Here is how I am setting the anchor point of the view. I'm using this as the view disappears when setting its anchor point otherwise.

```
func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
            var newPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
            var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y: bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y);

            newPoint = newPoint.applying(transform)
            oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(transform)

            var position = layer.position

            position.x -= oldPoint.x
            position.x += newPoint.x

            position.y -= oldPoint.y
            position.y += newPoint.y

            layer.position = position
            layer.anchorPoint = point
}
```

Once the full 360 rotation is complete I would then need to move the view back in towards the center, completing the animation.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399892/how-to-create-a-caanimation-effect-like-moon-rotates-around-the-earth-and-rotate

Comment: Take a look at the link above, I've added a swift implementation. I might help with rotating the view around the center viewthe

Answer (score 0):

For the part when the loading view rotates around the circle view, you can use a UIBezierPath and create a CAKeyframeAnimation based on its path.
Take a look at this implementation. Hope it helps.

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {

    var circlePath: UIBezierPath!
    lazy var loader = makeLoader()
    lazy var centerView = makeCenterView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    
    func makeLoader() -> UIButton {
        let padding: CGFloat = 100
        let width = self.view.frame.width - (2 * padding)
        let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: padding, y: 200, width: width, height: 50))
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        b.backgroundColor = .blue
        return b
    }
    
    func makeCenterView() -> UIView {
        let width: CGFloat = 20
        let height: CGFloat = 20
        let x = self.view.center.x - width/2
        let y = self.view.center.y - height/2
        
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }

    func setup() {
        //create a UIBezierPath with a center that is at the center of the green view and a radius that has a length as the distance between the green view and the blue view.
        let arcCenterX = centerView.center.x
        let arcCenterY = centerView.center.y
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: arcCenterX, y: arcCenterY)
        let radius = arcCenterY - loader.center.y
        let startAngle = -CGFloat.pi/2
        let endAngle = CGFloat.pi*(1.5)
        
        let arcPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius:  radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        self.circlePath = arcPath
        
        self.view.addSubview(loader)
        self.view.addSubview(centerView)
    }
    
    @objc func didTap() {
        //create a CAKeyframeAnimation with a path that matches the UIBezierPath above.
        let loadAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        loadAnimation.path = self.circlePath.cgPath
        loadAnimation.calculationMode = .paced
        loadAnimation.duration = 2.0
        loadAnimation.rotationMode = .rotateAuto
        
        loadAnimation.repeatCount = Float(CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        loader.layer.add(loadAnimation, forKey: "circleAnimation")
    }

}
```